# How to cluster EHCache with play framework 2

Tags: playframework-2.0, ehcache

I have never used EHCache before but I realized it is the default cache for playframework versions 2.x. Is it possible to run one instance of EHCache separately on a different server and point multiple app servers to it (how would you configure that)? or does it have to be run as part of the JVM which app-server is running on? in that case how would you make the EHCache of multiple appservers aware of each other?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way of doing so using EHCache and Play Framework 2.x
the solution is to take care of caching outside of what play provides. Using memcached is one option and there are play plugins for it.

Comment: EHCache is a distributed cache why there is no way? what is the reason?